# .gitignore file is not working, and git status still shows the files listed inside .gitignore

Tags: git

[The Git Bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYw4N.png)
[sublime text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fxYr.png)

I access the .gitignore file through sublime text 3, and have already saved encoded as UTF-8 without BOM. I used the `git rm -rf --cached .`  command thrice so far before using `git add .` again, but every time the files I want to ignore are showing up in my "untracked" list. Inside dir2 is app2.js
"

Comment: Hi Confused, and welcome do Stack Overflow. Adding "SOLVED" to the title is not the correct way to treat solutions here. If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. If not, you can [answer and accept your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). See also [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Eduardo Baitello thanks, I'm new to this :)

Comment: A problem due to a typo is trivial and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.gitignore` is nothing but an another file which needs to be committed. If you keep on changing the content in it without committing the changes then it won't work.

Please add the `files/pattern/regax` in `.gitignore` as per your need and ensure to commit those changes.

That's it! next time when you are working, you won't see those files in "untracked" list.

Let me know if you still face the issue!

Comment: I committed the .gitignore file with all the relevant files inside, but they're still showing up in my untracked list
Edit: It was a name issue, thank you for the answer regardless

Comment: No worries, Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

if u commit the file before the .gitignore,you can try  `git rm file`